# Why is this substitution failure occuring in SFINAE-based reflection?

Tags: c++, reflection, sfinae

I have written code that detects if one object can be streamed into an `std::ostream`.  However, while it works in clang, it fails in gcc.  After simplifying the code, the problem seems to occur when two classes have operator<< defined in different namespaces.

Below is the (simplified) code (and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nVLwhW) it is on godbolt):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace test_ns {
  // Define two (trivial) classes.
  class Class1 { };
  class Class2 { };

  // First class has ostream operator defined in namespace test_ns
  std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Class1 & v) {
    return out << "Class1 Output!";
  }
}

// Second class as ostream operator defined in global namespace.
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const test_ns::Class2 & v) {
  return out << "Class2 Output!";
}

namespace test_ns {
  // Simple template that always evaluates to bool (for SFINAE-based reflection)
  template <typename EVAL_TYPE> using bool_decoy = bool;

  // Two version of HasPrint that test the operator<< into ostream.
  // First version preferred if << works...
  template <typename T>
  bool HasPrint(bool_decoy<decltype( std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>() )>) {
    return true;
  }

  // Second version as a fallback.
  template <typename T>
  bool HasPrint(...) {
    return false;
  }

}

int main()
{
  std::cout << test_ns::HasPrint<test_ns::Class2>(true) << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the error I receive in gcc 9.1:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'bool test_ns::HasPrint(test_ns::bool_decoy<decltype ((declval<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&>() << declval<T>()))>) [with T = test_ns::Class2; test_ns::bool_decoy<decltype ((declval<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&>() << declval<T>()))> = <type error>]':

<source>:40:55:   required from here

<source>:26:68: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'test_ns::Class2')

   26 |   bool HasPrint(bool_decoy<decltype( std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>() )>) {

      |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(followed by a long list of candidates)

While I can (and will) refactor the code to circumvent this issue, I don't fully understand what is going wrong here.  Am I improperly defining the operators, or is this a problem with gcc?

Comment: Generally you should put all operators in the same namespace as the class.  That allows ADL to function.

Comment: @NathanOliver - That's useful to know; I was assuming that operators defined outside of the class should go in the global namespace to be accessed properly, but I wasn't familiar with the rule.  In this case, though, I think it should be correct either way, if not necessarily best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, as hinted by NathanOliver, is that your `operator<<` in the global namespace isn’t found by ADL, and it can’t be found by **unqualified** lookup from `test_ns::HasPrint` because of `test_ns::operator<<`.  The interesting question is why Clang finds it anyway.  I can only assume that `decltype` is somehow confusing it.

Comment: I've now tried it with both the Intel compiler and MSVC, and the code compiles in both.  My reading of ADL seems to indicate that the targeted namespace should be checked first, but that the others should be checked as well.  Indeed, if I remove the definition of Class1, but leave Class2 defined in the namespace, but with its operator<< in the global namespace, the code compiles everywhere...  So it seems like it must be some kind of interaction between the two in GCC.

Comment: @CharlesOfria: Actually, I bet we’re seeing DR1558 (so it’s the `using`, not the `decltype`)—what language version are you using?